# How to color one "panel" of ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, color

Here is my code:

```
data = Table[{i, j, RandomInteger[{1, 10}]}, {i, 5}, {j, 5}];
thePlot = ListPlot3D[Flatten[data, 1], InterpolationOrder -> {0}]
```

How can I make the data at one point, say (3,4), a different color.  I want to highlight that data.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 7):

```
SeedRandom[69];
data = Table[{i, j, RandomInteger[{1, 10}]}, {i, 5}, {j,  5}];      
ListPlot3D[Flatten[data, 1], InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
          ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
          ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 
                            If[ChessboardDistance[{x, y}, {3, 4}] <= .5 && 
                               z == Last@data[[3, 4]], Red, Blue, Green]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

```
thePlot = 
 Show[ { ListPlot3D[Flatten[data, 1], InterpolationOrder -> {0}], 
   Graphics3D[{Red, 
     Cuboid[# - {0, 0, 1/100}, # + {1/2, 1/2, 1/100}] &@
      Flatten[data, 1][[3]]}]
   }]
```

[image]

Comment: your solution is robust.